JMeter - Pattern Matching for Multiple Values in Response Body and Iterating through them
I am currently working on trying to collect multiple body responses that indicate to me which requests need to be sent based on what is returned to me. I need to iterate through the matches I received, but I am struggling to figure out the logic.
Below is what I currently have received.. I was finding something like "name=pyLoadingMessage_D_CreditCardAccount_pa532535232pz.pxResults(1)_3
All I need is minimum the number between pa 532535232 and pz, but also the argument being passed in pxResults(1). This argument allows me to know how many requests need to be sent, so say it could be up to 8 of these in the body response.
I was able to extract both and concatenate it;however, I'm not exactly sure how to write the logic to do this.
They're AJAX requests and so later on I will utilize a Parallel Controller to run them simultaneously (up to 6 at a time). In the requests, they're the same, the only thing I need is D_CreditCardAccount_pa532535232pz.pxResults(1) for example. I considered utilizing a loop controller, and at first I was planning to make it loop through the amount of matches found, but that makes no sense since I am running these in parallel and not sequentially.
Any tips would be appreciated to write the logic out for these.
def i = 1
def results = []
 
// Iterate through all matches using a while loop
while (vars.get("accountInfo_" + i) != null) {
    // Get the current match value
    def match = vars.get("accountInfo_" + i)
    // Use a regular expression to extract the parts of interest
    def paPzPattern = /pa(\d+)pz\.pxResults\((\d+)\)/
    def matcher = (match =~ paPzPattern)
    if (matcher) {
        // Extract the number between pa and pz, and the number in pxResults()
        def paNumber = matcher[0][1]
        def pxResultNumber = matcher[0][2]
        // Concatenate the results in the desired format
        def concatenatedResult = "pa${paNumber}_pxResult(${pxResultNumber})"
        // Store or log the result
        results.add(concatenatedResult)
        log.info("Extracted and processed match: ${concatenatedResult}")
    }
    // Increment the counter
    i++
}
 
// Optionally, return or use the list of results
return results.join(', ')  ```



I don't think Parallel Controller will do the trick for you, I would suggest the following:

Instead of return results.join(', ')  put this results into a JMeter Variable like:
vars.putObject('results', results)


Then add a Parallel Sampler (an empty one) where you need to send AJAX requests

Add a JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of the Parallel Sampler and put the following code into "Script" area:
vars.getObject('results').each { result ->
    sampler.addURL('http://example.com?parameter=' + result)
}

of course amend the URL according to your needs



thanks for the response. These AJAX requests are actually POST requests that I need  to use. How would I change the Parameters in the body on a Parallel Sampler and make it a POST request?

One thing to note as well is that, I don't know how many AJAX requests are sending until it's extracted from a previous request. Pretty much the parameters, url and whatnot is the same, the only thing is that one value that changes pxResults(1). Should I use a ForEach Controller to iterate through it? Not sure how to achieve this with Parallel Sampler

At the moment it's hard-coded to be GET you can either set it to POST and re-build the plugin or Open a BlazeMeter Support Ticket and ask them to make this configurable

Awesome! Good to know I can do that. Am I able to change the parameters in the JSR223 PreProcessor that is the child of parallel sampler to include different parameters once I change it to a POST request? For example, I would need to to set something like arrayValue = D_CreditCardAccount_pa532535232pz.pxResults(1) basically. I assume having an outer foreach loop should iterate through all the values?

I don't really understand what you mean, if you know Groovy it might be easier to send the AJAX  HTTP requests with Groovy and response time will be the time of the slowest request. You can also add a SubResult for each request if you want to record execution time of each one.
